# Angular custom npm package 'Cannot find module'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-library

I have created a custom npm package library, I have successfully created it and published on npm and then installed the package using `npm install <my-package-name>`.
And now I am facing issue on importing the package.When I import it in app.module.ts file its shows:

> Cannot find module 'my-module-name' or its corresponding type declarations.

I have also tried by deleting the node-modules and package-lock.json files and then npm install but sadly it's not works.

Comment: Try adding '.d' at the end of the import.

Comment: import { LongPipeModule }  from 'long-pipe.d';
like this?

Comment: Yes, if this doesn't work you should add some relevant code so we can help you out.

Comment: Fixed, I was made a mistake, after npm login, and before publishig the library we have to run ng build command.
So that's why module was build and gives error 'cannot find module'.